# Can I make a generic by using the definite article?

Tags: definite-article, generic-noun-phrases

Can I make the word "noun" into a generic with the definite article ?

Ex)

***The*** **noun** can be a subject or object.

Comment: Yes  you can. Just like *the leopard can be found in the wild both in Africa and in Asia*.

Comment: But, someone said it can't be used.

Comment: But notice you need to talk about the whole noun phrase *the noun* not just the noun by itself.

Comment: I see that answer. I disagree. It provides no acceptable rationale for saying no. Maybe @Lawler can comment.

Comment: But, the leopard is just the leopard by itself.

Comment: Who is Lawler???

Comment: The generic noun phrase is *the leopard*. I mean you should be talking about generic noun phrases, not as you do in your question: can I make some noun generic by using the.

Comment: Dr John @Lawler is a linguist whose dissertation was on generic noun phrases and who wrote [this nice summary](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) of the three types of generic noun phrases and their differences in meaning.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No.

A noun can function as a subject or object.

Here 'a' does the job you were looking for. You could also say 'Nouns can function...'

If you say 'the noun', that means you have a particular noun in mind - 'giraffe' for instance.

Edit: There are cases where generic noun phrases can be made with 'the' but here it sounds strange and is ambiguous.

Comment: Can only things like cars and tigers be used with "the"?

Comment: I can play the piano. The kangaroo is the best known mammal in Australia. More often than not we don't use it for a general class of things. I would learn examples of it as exceptions.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  "The noun" is just a generic noun phrase just like "The giraffe".  I agree it sounds a little unusual and stuffy to say "the noun", but to simply say "no" is just wrong.

Comment: Yes; you're right. My mistake. Ex. Of all the parts of speech, the noun is the easiest to use. I jumped to a conclusion because the example sentence in the question was ambiguous and confusing.